# Typical flow of BigData/Hadoop project?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata, sqoop

I have started learning BigData technologies like SQOOP, Hive, Pig recently and found that there are multiple alternatives (like SQOOP, HiveQL etc.) available to solve a given problem. I am bit confused about the choice of technology/ tool.

If you take any typical Microsoft BI project most of the time the flow would be

SSIS (to process the raw data) -> SSAS (to create OLAP DB) -> SSRS (to generate reports).

Analogous to this, what would be the typical flow of a BigData/Hadoop project. Assume that my data source is Email Logs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It actually depends on whats the requirement and what set of skills you have. In my opinion you can process the email logs in multiple ways.

Options

1. (Near Real Time) Stream email logs from source using flume ---> Store logs as in HDFS in flume sink ---> analyse the logs using either Pig or Hive.
2. (Real Time) Stream email logs using Storm spouts ---> process the logs in storm bolts ---> store them finnaly ins nosql database for further reporting and analysis.

There are many other ways to do it. Based on the available skill set which will fit for your requirements you can decide.

Comment: Hi Srinivasan, Thanq for your valuable comments. Assume I do not required to process the data in real time. I just have to run a overnight job and i know only Pig, Hive and Sqoop. So can I follow the following process ? --Pig to collect data and process it and store it in Hive. Then Sqoop to put data in some RDBMS for reporting purpose

Comment: Yes you can very well follow your approach to process the log files in pig and create a intermediate output.--->  Use these intermediate output files to Hive external table ---> using sqoop export to your RDBMS.